# How do i get my extended family to cooperate

Tags: kashrut-kosher, conversion-to-judaism, kavod

Im in the process of converting (its going to be a while). Anyway I've been doing the best i can to cook kosher style food. Today i had lunch with my mom who decided she was going to feed my son shrimp even after i told her no. How do i get her to understand? Alsohow do i continue to honor her when she's doing these things? I've told her he won't eat it, we don't eat shrimp anymore but she doesn't care.

Edit: where can i find more information on this to find the answers i need

Comment: This happens with my family and they're non-religious Jews. Be patient with them, and invite them over to eat more often than you eat at their place. Bring kosher meat with you and maybe your own treif-free pots and pans rather than expecting them to buy it

Comment: Welcome! How old is your son? Is he planning on converting, too?

Comment: My kids are 12, 2, 5 months. The 12 year old doesn't want to convert, the 2 year old is the one from today. Thanks for replying

Comment: How is this a request for *p'sak*?  It's a practical question for a "Jewish life" problem, of which we have many.  A good answer would talk about both *halacha* for a convert's non-Jewish parents (a situation most Jews don't have to deal with) *and* the communication/boundary-setting aspects of working out differences involving observance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Cas and welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Your question is a heartfelt one and is probably what is called off topic here. You should take the tour in the Help Center for details. (It's in the Question Mark link in the upper right of the screen.)

Congratulations on you choice to pursue a Jewish life and I wish you success in your effort. You should probably direct your question to whatever Orthodox Rabbi is assisting you in the process of conversion.

But that said, you may be upset over something that isn't an issue. If the biological mother of your son is not Jewish, then your son is also not Jewish and would be permitted, even after you convert, to consume shrimp given to him by your mother without reservation. No sin or transgression would be involved.

If your son, is born of a Jewish mother, then you and your son's mother should be understanding, respectful and polite, but firm that this is unacceptable treatment from your mother.

She may understand or she may not. This type of situation is one of the struggles that you may face for the rest of your life if you follow through with conversion to Judaism. You need to be sure that your commitment is strong enough to cope with that possibility.

Remember that for your Mother, she loves you and her grandson, just like always. Your change may be difficult for her or she may never understand and accept it. You should still love and honor your parents and respect them as always, even more so because that is also a mitzvah for a Jew. But if you continue on this path, she will need to respect whatever boundaries you set for your Jewish household.

Comment: Thanks for your input.My kids are 12, 2, and 5 months. They are all my biological kids. Today it was the 2 year old. The religion I'm leavingalso has some dietary laws that she very much enjoyed making my children break (no coffee or tea for example and she woulddrink it and tell them to tellme it's lemonade). Through DNA testing i have Jewish ancestors through my mothers family. My 12 year old doesn't want to convert but he doesn't argue with any changes.

Comment: @Cas I can’t tell from what you are saying whether you are a man or a woman. DNA testing is not the measure to determine whether you are a Jew by birth or not. Again, you should be discussing your specifics with your supervising Orthodox Rabbi. That you are bringing 3 (presumed to be non-Jewish) children with you is an enormous hurdle which you do not currently appreciate. It sounds like your current background is someone leaving LDS or some offshoot. People from that background have great respect for the Jewish people & if that is your case, may explain your current choices.

Comment: But leaving LDS doesn’t mean that you must become a Jew to serve G-d properly, even according the Torah. If you and your children are non-Jewish currently, you can choose the life path of what is called Bnei Noach (the descendants of Noah) and still be seen as a completely righteous individual but will sidestep the difficulty you are having with your mother. Perhaps G-d is steering you in that direction.

Comment: @Cas, you might do well to ask the question on the Interpersonal StackExchange site (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com), especially given your point about your mother-in-law deliberately misleading your children and telling them to lie to you.

Comment: And by the way, best wishes in whatever you choose, whether it's to continue with becoming Jewish or, as Yaacov said, to follow the [Noahide Laws](https://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/2123/oq/Seven%20Noahide%20Laws/jewish/Noahide-Laws-The-Seven.htm).

Comment: @Meir Good advice. Cas didn’t refer to her Mother-in-law. She said her Mother. Which would suggest that her Mother didn’t accept the dietary restrictions of LDS either. That would either mean her Mother left LDS before Cas or that Cas became a member of LDS on her own and her Mother didn’t accept Cas’ choice. Either way, there are clear family issues going on outside of any potential choice to become a Jew. And that doesn’t address why Cas left whatever faith she was a part of. Is there an estranged husband/father involved here? Probably. And that further complicates this whole picture.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes it's LDS (and so much to unlearn). My husband isnt supportive but he's more scared becauseof the recent shootings and attacks than just being against it. It's my choice to leave and return to what my ancestors left (which is why i know i have to convert). I've alwaysfelt drawn to do it but my mother never approved so i didn't.it's complicated slightly. It's hard because i was raised to honor my mother. I think the confusing part for me the line of honoring her and teaching my kids. Again thank you all for your advice and answers and patience with me.